# Find out camera world width and height?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, camera, screen

So here is my problem in a nutshell:
I want to know how spawn an object in the middle of the screen, which means I want find the screen's width and height values in World units.

> Camera Position: 0,23,-10
>
> Camera Rotation: 60,0,0

So I have tried this:

```
Vector3 screenWorldSize = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, -10));

// In the Update function
If(Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.P))
{
GameObject tempObject = Instantiate(gamePrefab);
tempObject.transform.position = new Vector3(screenWorldSize.x, 1.5f, 10f);
}
```

But the tempObject position is not correct (Not in the middle), So I tried to `Debug.Log(screenWorldSize)` and I get this result `(-10.3, 28.8, -20.0)`

I tried using `Camera.main.ViewPortToWorldPoint()` with `(0,0,-10)` and `(1,0,-10)` and I got almost the same result.

Here is an image of the scene..
[image: Scene Image]

**Is there something that I don't understand?**
**How to get the screen edges in World points?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310558/unity3d-move-ui-object-to-center-of-screen-while-maintaining-its-parenting

Comment: Hi. Its not a duplicate. Please read the question again My question is not about ui at all, and the question you is no way near of solving my problem.

Comment: Hi.
And this doesn't work for you?
tempObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 10)

Comment: Hi again, unfortunately no! this is why I need more help. Believe me I have read almost every Question/Post/Blog about this issue and non of them worked. I'm telling you it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. You don't need the width and height at all, you just need the direction.

```
// this is a vector matching the camera's direction
Vector3 cameraDirection = Camera.main.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward;
// this is the camera position
Vector3 cameraPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
```

If you want to just create the object a certain distance from the camera, you can do this to get its position

```
Vector3 position = cameraPosition + cameraDirection * distance;
```

If you want to spawn the object on another object pointed at by the camera, you need this:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(cameraPosition, cameraDirection, out hit))
{
    Vector3 position = hit.point;
    [..]
}
```